# Is there a way I can increment a value in the model upon a users activity like commenting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to increment a users current earning value each time he/she makes a comment on a blog. I'm writing a crypto program with Node and Express for Backend and MongoDB for database. I want to be able to increment a users earned amount (current) per comments they make in the platform.

I have tried adding a "earnings" field to the user model, and set it to Number because that's what I actually need. Then I wrote a some lines of code to increment a users current amount upon making comments anywhere in the application (blog) but it doesn't seem to work. Instead it returns the same number which is 20. I set it to add 20 per comment but it always returns 20 and not 20, 40, 60 ... My code is below

```
    // my model
    var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        username: String,
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        earnings: 0,
        email: String,
        password: String
    })


    // my routes
router.post('/', middleware.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    // find blog using ID
    Blog.findById(req.params.id, (err, blog) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log('Error:', err);
            res.redirect('/blogs');
        } else {
            Comment.create(req.body.comment, (err, comment) => {
                if(err) {
                    req.flash('error', 'Something went wrong');
                    console.log('Error:', err);
                } else {
                    // add id
                    comment.author.id = req.user._id;
                    comment.author.username = req.user.username;
                    var total = Number(req.user.earnings);
                    // save comment
                    comment.save();
                    User.earnings = total;
                    User.earnings += 20;
                    blog.comments.push(comment);
                    blog.save();
                    res.redirect('/blogs/' + blog._id);
                    console.log(req.user.earnings);
                    console.log(User.earnings);
                }
            })
        }
    });
});
```

I expect the earnings value to increment and get saved per comment for a specific user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to update the user's document after creating the comment. Currenlty you are just doing `User.earning += 20`, but not specifying which user and not even saving it. You need to use `User.findOneAndUpdate` and `$inc` to increase a number value.

**Try this :**

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id : req.user._id},{$inc : {earnings : 20}});
```

instead of

```
User.earnings = total;
User.earnings += 20;
```

And only after the update query has been successfully executed, you will be able to verify that it has been updated.

Also, i would suggest to create Your Comment document and save it all at once.
Also, earning wont be reflected in the req.user object, so you need to modify it yourself.
'
Your query should look like this :

```
Comment.create(req.body.comment, (err, comment) => {
    if(err) {
        req.flash('error', 'Something went wrong');
        console.log('Error:', err);
    } else {
        // add id
        comment.author.id = req.user._id;
        comment.author.username = req.user.username;
        var total = Number(req.user.earnings);
        // save comment
        comment.save();
        User.findOneAndUpdate({_id : req.user._id},{$inc : {earnings : 20}})
            .then((err,user) => {
                 console.log(user.earnings)
            });
        blog.comments.push(comment);
        blog.save();
        res.redirect('/blogs/' + blog._id);
        console.log(req.user.earnings); //i dont think your req.user object will be updated by itself
        console.log(User.earnings);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "$inc" operator to increment any numerical value. Also, use 'update' rather than 'save' to update a document.

Ref: [MongoDB Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/)